# populating data from multiple async sources in angularjs and merging in an object

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to angularJS and the whole concept of deferred/promises so this might not be the cleanest of the codes but want to know what am i doing wrong here.

Basically in factory in my first async call I'm fetching data(stockname and quantity) from Firebase then 
in my second async call I'm trying to get additional details like current price using $http. While i successfully get the details I'm unable to merge it in an object in my controller and show it as a table using ng-repeat.

```
//below is my Factory snippet
factory.getStocks = function(){
var promise =  firebase.database().ref().child("Stock").once('value');
var qpromise = $q.when(promise).then(callback)
return stock;
};


function callback(snapshot){   
var i=0;
snapshot.forEach(function(child)
{
   stocks[i] = {
        name: child.key,
        holding: child.val(),
        price: -1,
        value: -1
    };
   i = i+1;
  });
  return stocks;
}
```

Controller as below: but get an error "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference" I'm assuming since the stocks might not be populated yet. Is there a better way to populate the price

```
portfolio.controller('updatePortfolio', function($scope,stockFactory,$http){
init();

function init()
{
    $scope.stocks = stockFactory.getStocks();
}
}



function updatePrice()
{
    $http.get('//call for api')
    .then(function(response))
    {
        $scope.stocks[0].price = response.data;  //error "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"
    }
// similar call to update rest of the stocks... planning to do it using $q.all if i can somehow figure how to merge this.
}
});
```

front end:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Holding</th><th>Value</th>

</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="s in stocks">
    <td>{{s.name}}</td>
    <td>{{s.price}}</td>
    <td>{{s.holding}}</td>
    <td>{{s.price * s.holding}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an undefined object in your factory method. Return the promise of stocks instead.

```
factory.getStocks = function(){
  var promise =  firebase.database().ref().child("Stock").once('value');
  return promise.then(callback) //returns stocks
};
```

And in your controller

```
portfolio.controller('updatePortfolio', function($scope,stockFactory,$http){
   init();

   function init() {
      //set your scope variables inside the promise success handler
      stockFactory.getStocks().then(function(stocks) {
         $scope.stocks = stocks;
      }).then(function(){
        $http.get(api call).then(function(response) {
          $scope.stock[0].price = response.data;
      });
   }
  });
```